# Getting status by N last rows from each group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is simplified table([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0678/4)):

```
id  group   status
--  ------  -------
1   group1  success
2   group1  fail
3   group1  success

4   group2  success

5   group3  fail
6   group3  success
7   group3  success
8   group3  success
```

I need to get result info about failures for each group by N last rows.
Like this (N=3):

```
group   has_failures
------  ------------
group1  1
group2  0
group3  0
```

Getting groups is quite easy:

```
-- Select last row from each group:
SELECT a.id,  a.group, a.status
FROM log a
INNER JOIN(
    select max(i.id) as max_id 
    from log i
    group by i.group
) as b on a.id = b.max_id;
```

And failures too:

```
-- Select fail status by last 3 rows:
select count(g.status) > 0 as has_failures
from (
       SELECT a.group, a.status
       FROM log a
       WHERE a.group = 'group3'
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 3
     ) as g
where g.status = 'fail';
```

How should be these two queries merged, or maybe easier way exists?

Comment: Shouldn't your `group3` row have `has_failures` equal to `1`?

Comment: No, since 3 last entries for `group3` (ids 6, 7, 8) are `success`

Comment: Ah ok, then my answer is invalid. Didn't realize you were taking into account only the last 3 entries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option using `user defined variables` to establish a row number per group.  Then you can use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select max(t.id) id,
  t.group,
  max(case when t.rank = 1 then t.status end) status,
  sum(case when t.status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) hasfailures
from (
  select *, 
    case l.group 
      when @curGroup 
      then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
      else @curRow := 1 AND @curGroup := l.group 
    end + 1 AS rank
  from `log` l cross join (select @curRow:=0, @curGroup:='') c
  order by l.group, id desc
  ) t
where rank <= 3
group by t.group
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0678/38)